# Android InflateException in unknown class when creating alert from XML file

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-theme, android-dialog

I have changed the app theme from Theme.appcompat to Theme.MaterialComponents

error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rohindh.kcthappytummy, PID: 16582
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating 
class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at 
com.rohindh.kcthappytummy.Adapter.AddedtRecyclerAdapter.createpopup(AddedtRecyclerAdapter.java:70)
at 
com.rohindh.kcthappytummy.Adapter.AddedtRecyclerAdapter.access$000(AddedtRecyclerAdapter.java:26)
at 
com.rohindh.kcthappytummy.Adapter.AddedtRecyclerAdapter$1.onClick(AddedtRecyclerAdapter.java:62)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme 
to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
at 
com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
at
com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:458)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:417)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at 
com.rohindh.kcthappytummy.Adapter.AddedtRecyclerAdapter.createpopup(AddedtRecyclerAdapter.java:70) 
at     
com.rohindh.kcthappytummy.Adapter.AddedtRecyclerAdapter.access$000(AddedtRecyclerAdapter.java:26) 
at 
com.rohindh.kcthappytummy.Adapter.AddedtRecyclerAdapter$1.onClick(AddedtRecyclerAdapter.java:62) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

When user clicks the edit button, an Alert dialog window should appear but I don't know what I'm missing

Adapter code

```
public class AddedtRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddedtRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Dishmodel> dishmodellist;
//pop elements and requirement
private AlertDialog.Builder build;
private AlertDialog dialog;
private EditText nameedt,desedt,pricedt;
private ImageButton closebtn;
private Button addbtn;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
public AddedtRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Dishmodel> dishmodellist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dishmodellist = dishmodellist;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dish_list_item,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddedtRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Dishmodel dish= dishmodellist.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(dish.getName());
    holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(dish.getPrice()));
    holder.descirption.setText(dish.getDescription());
    //edit btn clicked then create a pop window and send the current array with is position
    holder.edtbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createpopup(dish,position);
        }
    });
}
private void createpopup(Dishmodel dish, int position) {
    build = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.popup,null);
    nameedt = view.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
    desedt = view.findViewById(R.id.itemdes);
    pricedt = view.findViewById(R.id.itemprice);
    addbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.itemaddbtn);
    closebtn = view.findViewById(R.id.closebtn);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.addprogress);
    build.setView(view);
    dialog = build.create();
    dialog.show();
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dishmodellist.size();
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name,descirption,price;
    ImageButton edtbtn,deletebtn;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishname);
        descirption = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishdes);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishprice);
        edtbtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editbtn);
        deletebtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deletebtn);}
}
```

error in 26 line in xml ie  `material.TextInputLayout`
xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="380dp" android:paddingHorizontal="10dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/closeicon"
        android:id="@+id/closebtn"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/appcolor"
        />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/addprogress"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Item Name"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/itemname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Item Description"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/itemdes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Item Price"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/itemprice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:inputType="number" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/appcolor"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/itemaddbtn"
    android:text="Add"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest code

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">false</item>
</style>
<style name="myDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'}
```

I have referred to many solutions in stackoverflow but can't able to solve this issue. If anyone knows solution for this issue please help out with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having changed themes, are you sure the new theme has the TextInputLayout you were using before?

Comment: yeah,it has TextInputLayout